# Django Fullcalendar Not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, fullcalendar

I will get straight to the point.

I'm using FullCalendar in mu application, and it's working fine, as aspected, but somehow, I have bugs when I try to render the calendar with ajax call, so the second time.

When I call the landing page, the view, calendar gets rendered properly, but when I try to filter down the calendars using ajax implementation, the rendering is lost!

I literally have no idea why is this happening, so any help will be great!

The idea is simple, when I land on the page, I have all calendars rendered, and if I want to chose the particular calendar group, I just want to do a basic filtering depending on the users data.

First, this is my function which handles the page :

```
@login_required(login_url='registration/login')
def add_event(request, pk):
    cal_group_param = request.GET.get('value_from_the_user', None) #Takes the users input from the frontend
    context = {}

    ...
    # Code which is nor relevant for this question
    ...

    events_all = Events.objects.all()

    if cal_group_param:
        calendars = Calendar.objects.all().filter(
            date_valid__gte=now.date(),
            calendar_master__group__cusopis=cal_group_param,
        ).order_by('date_valid')
    else:
        calendars = Calendar.objects.all().filter(
            date_valid__gte=now.date(),
            calendar_master__group__cusopis__icontains='default_group',
        ).order_by('date_valid')


    form = ZakaziForma()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ZakaziForma(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
                return redirect(success_page)

    context['cal_groups'] = cal_groups
    context['calendars'] = calendars
    context['form'] = form
    context['opp'] = opp
    context['events'] = events_all
    context["today"] = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    context["user"] = user
    context["user_groups"] = user_groups

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string(
            template_name='main/get_calendars.html',
            context={'calendars': calendars}
        )
        data_dict = {'html_from_view': html}
        return JsonResponse(data=data_dict, safe=False)

    return render(request, 'opportunity/detalji/zakazi.html', context=context)
```

As you can see its a simple function from this point and the data is returned properly, as expected.

As I said, when the function gets called for the first time (get request) the calendars are rendered. 
When the ajax gets called, the data is there, but the rendering is missing.

This is the first landing page :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Title {% endblock title %}

{% block content_row %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {% include 'main/partials/_link_fullcalendar.html' %} # Fullcalendar css links
    {{ form.media }}

    <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;text-align: center">
        <div class="container" style="width: 350px;">
            {% if calendars %}
                <div class="row" style="height: 8%">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="input-gruop">
                            <select id="calendar_filter" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                {% for group in cal_groups %} # Filtering option | working
                                    <option>{{ group }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'main:add_event' opp.pk %}">
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Kliknite za potvrdu.">Potvrdi</button>
                            <input type=button value="Povratak" class="btn btn-info"
                                   onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <h1>Trenutno nema napravljenih kalendara.</h1><br><br><br><br>
                {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                    <a class="btn btn-info" title="Kliknite za pravljenje kalendara."
                       href="{% url 'main:create_calendar' %}">Napravi kalendar</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="display_calendars"
             style="display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; height: 750px; width: max-content;">
            {% for cal in calendars %}
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('{{ cal.id }}');
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                            minTime: "07:00:00",
                            maxTime: "22:00:00",
                            businessHours: {
                                startTime: '09:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                                endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                            },
                            height: 'auto',
                            locale: 'sr',
                            plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                            defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
                            header: {
                                center: '{{ cal.date_valid|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                                // right: 'timeGridDay,dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                            },
                            defaultDate: "{{ cal.date_valid|date:"Y-m-d" }}",
                            views: {
                                timeGridThreeDay: {
                                    type: 'timeGrid',
                                    duration: {days: 3},
                                    buttonText: '3 Dana'
                                }
                            },
                            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views

                            select: function (arg) {
                                var start = moment(arg.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                var end = moment(arg.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                var cal_id = {{ cal.id }};

                                $('#id_start_date').val(start);
                                $('#id_end_date').val(end);
                                $('#id_calendar').val(cal_id);
                                //calendar.unselect()
                            },
                            selectMinDistance: 0,
                            slotDuration: '00:30:00',
                            editable: true,
                            selectable: true,
                            selectMirror: true,
                            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                            eventTextColor: 'black',
                            events: [
                                {% for i in events %}
                                    {% if i.calendar_id == cal.id %}
                                        {
                                            id: "{{ i.event_id }}",
                                            calendar: "{{ i.calendar }}",
                                            calendar_id: "{{ i.calendar_id }}",
                                            title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                                            start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                                            end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

                                        },
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            ]
                        });

                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        calendar1.render();
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    });
                </script>

                <div style="display: flex; height: 1000px" class="container">
                    <div class="container" id='{{ cal.id }}'>{{ cal.calendar_master.name }}</div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'main/partials/_fullcalendar_script.html' %} #Fullcalendar script links

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar_filter').change(function () {
                let option = $(this).find('option:selected');
                let selected_value = option.val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{% url 'main:add_event' opp.pk %}',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        'value_from_the_user': selected_value,
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#display_calendars').html(data.html_from_view);
                        console.log(data.html_from_view);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Please report this error: " + errorThrown + xhr.status + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>

{% endblock content_row %}
```

This is the get_calendars page :

```
{% for cal in calendars %}
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            let calendarEl = document.getElementById('{{ cal.id }}');
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                minTime: "07:00:00",
                maxTime: "22:00:00",
                businessHours: {
                    startTime: '09:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                    endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                },
                height: 'auto',
                locale: 'sr',
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
                header: {
                    center: '{{ cal.date_valid|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    // right: 'timeGridDay,dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                },
                defaultDate: "{{ cal.date_valid|date:"Y-m-d" }}",
                views: {
                    timeGridThreeDay: {
                        type: 'timeGrid',
                        duration: {days: 3},
                        buttonText: '3 Dana'
                    }
                },
                navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views

                select: function (arg) {
                    var start = moment(arg.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    var end = moment(arg.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    var cal_id = {{ cal.id }};

                    $('#id_start_date').val(start);
                    $('#id_end_date').val(end);
                    $('#id_calendar').val(cal_id);
                    //calendar.unselect()
                },
                selectMinDistance: 0,
                slotDuration: '00:30:00',
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                selectMirror: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                eventTextColor: 'black',
                events: [
                    {% for i in events %}
                        {% if i.calendar_id == cal.id %}
                            {
                                id: "{{ i.event_id }}",
                                calendar: "{{ i.calendar }}",
                                calendar_id: "{{ i.calendar_id }}",
                                title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                                start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                                end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

                            },
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                ]
            });

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            calendar1.render();
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        });
    </script>

    <div style="display: flex; height: 1000px" class="container">
        <div class="container" id='{{ cal.id }}'>{{ cal.calendar_master.name }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The url :

```
    path('dodaj/<int:pk>', add_event, name='add_event'),
```

And this is the complete page source after the ajax call, when the rendering gets lost :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="dev.Ink">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/login/favicon.ico"/>
         <div class="container" id="display_calendars"
             style="display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; height: 750px; width: max-content;">

                <script>
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('427');
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                            minTime: "07:00:00",
                            maxTime: "22:00:00",
                            businessHours: {
                                startTime: '09:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                                endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                            },
                            height: 'auto',
                            locale: 'sr',
                            plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                            defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
                            header: {
                                center: '2020-06-09',
                                // right: 'timeGridDay,dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                            },
                            defaultDate: "2020-06-09",
                            views: {
                                timeGridThreeDay: {
                                    type: 'timeGrid',
                                    duration: {days: 3},
                                    buttonText: '3 Dana'
                                }
                            },
                            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views

                            select: function (arg) {
                                var start = moment(arg.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                var end = moment(arg.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                var cal_id = 427;

                                $('#id_start_date').val(start);
                                $('#id_end_date').val(end);
                                $('#id_calendar').val(cal_id);
                                //calendar.unselect()
                            },
                            selectMinDistance: 0,
                            slotDuration: '00:30:00',
                            editable: true,
                            selectable: true,
                            selectMirror: true,
                            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                            eventTextColor: 'black',
                            events: [

                            ]
                        });

                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        calendar1.render();
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    });
                </script>

                <div style="display: flex; height: 1000px" class="container">
                    <div class="container" id='427'></div>
                </div>

                <script>
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('426');
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                            minTime: "07:00:00",
                            maxTime: "22:00:00",
                            businessHours: {
                                startTime: '09:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                                endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                            },
                            height: 'auto',
                            locale: 'sr',
                            plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                            defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
                            header: {
                                center: '2020-06-09',
                                // right: 'timeGridDay,dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                            },
                            defaultDate: "2020-06-09",
                            views: {
                                timeGridThreeDay: {
                                    type: 'timeGrid',
                                    duration: {days: 3},
                                    buttonText: '3 Dana'
                                }
                            },
                            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views

                            select: function (arg) {
                                var start = moment(arg.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                var end = moment(arg.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                var cal_id = 426;

                                $('#id_start_date').val(start);
                                $('#id_end_date').val(end);
                                $('#id_calendar').val(cal_id);
                                //calendar.unselect()
                            },
                            selectMinDistance: 0,
                            slotDuration: '00:30:00',
                            editable: true,
                            selectable: true,
                            selectMirror: true,
                            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                            eventTextColor: 'black',
                            events: [

                            ]
                        });

                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        calendar1.render();
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    });
                </script>

                <div style="display: flex; height: 1000px" class="container">
                    <div class="container" id='426'></div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>

<script src="/static/fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js"></script>
<script src="/static/fullcalendar/packages/core/locales/sr.js"></script>
<script src='/static/fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='/static/fullcalendar/packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='/static/fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='/static/fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar_filter').change(function () {
                let option = $(this).find('option:selected');
                let selected_value = option.val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/td/termini/dodaj/411582',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        'value_from_the_user': selected_value,
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#display_calendars').html(data.html_from_view);
                        console.log(data.html_from_view);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Please report this error: " + errorThrown + xhr.status + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
</div>

<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="/static/dash/vendor/jquery/jqueryfull.js"></script>


<script src="/static/dash/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="/static/dash/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="/static/dash/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="/static/dash/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/static/dash/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="/static/dash/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/static/dash/js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>
<script src="/static/dash/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
            <img src="/static/debug_toolbar/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" class="djdt-loader">
                    <div class="djdt-scroll"></div>

                </div>
            </div>




    <div id="djDebugWindow" class="djdt-panelContent"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I deleted the code which was unnecessary since it's too big. But as you can see, both calendars are there, but there's not visual as before the ajax call.

I am posting similar question for the 5th time, I can't believe that there's no one who has any idea what this could be.

Thanks!

EDITED :

This is before the ajax call : 
[image: before]

This is after the ajax call :

[image: after]

As you can see, when I inspect the page the data is there :

[image: with data]

Comment: Did you notice you're including jQuery twice in your page? That can't be helping. It can cause conflicts and other weird behaviour. Remove the "slim" version, you don't need it. And did you check your Console for errors when this problem is happening?

Comment: Oh actually, **three** times in fact - you've got jqueryfull.js and jquery.min.js in there too. Declare **one** version of jQuery in your page (just make sure it's included before you try to use code which requires it).

Comment: Anyway your filtering functionality appears to remove all the calendar HTML and JavaScript from the page and overwrite it with a new version. That likely won't work, because any JavaScript returned in the AJAX call won't be executed.

Comment: Anyway that's really inefficient - why rip up the whole calendar and re-draw it just because someone applied a filter? Just show and hide the calendar elements instead using Javascript. Re-creating the calendar every time, or using AJAX for anything, is not really necessary for a simple filter operation.

Comment: Or another idea: why have you even got multiple calendars at all? Why not just have one calendar with multiple [event sources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources) instead? It can show the events in each source in different colours for example, so you can tell them apart. And then you can simply filter the event sources, [adding and removing](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source) them when the user changes the filter. No need to reload calendars, or make new AJAX calls, or anything inefficient like that.

Comment: Actually thanks for the heads up, ill remove other jQuery includes. Regarding the filtering, what do you mean by just show and hide the calendar? Should I do that on Django side or with js only? Basically the ajax is telling the server which  calendar group should be showed, right?

Comment: The structure is way bigger than this part I shared, so the logic needs to stay the same unfortunately, regarding the event sources.

Comment: _"Should I do that on Django side or with js only"_ "using JavaScript" were my exact words. There's no need to do it with Django/python - changing the appearance of the page is a client-side only job (unless new data is needed from the server, but in this case it isn't). As long as you give the calendar divs IDs (or classes, or data-attributes) by which to match them to the selected filter options, then you can just write some Javascript to show or hide the correct divs when the filter is applied.

Comment: "the ajax is telling the server which calendar group should be showed"...not really, the user does that when they select the filter. Then you're sending that data from the client to the server, just so the server can send back some HTML. This is the same as my point above: the server doesn't really need to know or care about this at all. The server has sent the same data to the browser already, it doesn't need to send it again. The browser code can show or hide bits of that HTML according to the user's preference.

Comment: Hmmm, theoretically I agree with you. I'll try to implement that. I'm not so familiar with js so I tried to stick with the basics only.

Comment: _"the logic needs to stay the same unfortunately, regarding the event sources."_ ...really, why? Your server knows about calendar groups, and it associates a certain set of events with each group. Everything else about your calendars is identical (and hard-coded) apart from the event data. So the server-side can stick with this concept, but the front-end could be reconfigured to represent those two sets of events in fullCalendar event sources, rather than separate calendars. It's all about how the front-end uses the data, again the back-end doesn't need to know details of that.

Comment: (The only back-end change required for that approach would be to have an endpoint in Django which can return the event data for a particular group in JSON format. It would just mean taking some of your existing code which outputs the events data and moving it to another action.)

Comment: The other thing which is crucial is that I don't have much experience with frontend technologies, so as I said, I try to stick with the basics as much as I can, until I learn enough. If I wanted to implement the logic on the frontend side, with events handler or event sources, I suppose the more knowledge is needed in that case, right?

Comment: Showing/hiding elements isn't really any more difficult than making an AJAX request. Probably easier, if anything. You've already got `$('#calendar_filter').change(function () {
                let option = $(this).find('option:selected');
                let selected_value = option.val();` to detect the user changing the filter and get their selection. Now you just replace the AJAX bit with some code which shows or hides individual calendar divs depending on whether the calendar it contains is allowed by the filter or not.

Comment: Great than! But how could I know which calendar belongs to which group (using js)?

Comment: Should I filter the elements using data-attribute or?

Comment: Like I said, when you first use python to draw the calendar, you need to add an attribute to each calendar div which tells you the group (e.g. a class would do, or a data attribute, it doesn't really matter).